# how to use unique filter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

how to use unique filter in angularjs

```
$scope.students = [  
   { name: 'Hai', createdBy:'Thomas', createdOn:'09-09-2016' },  
   { name: 'Hal', createdBy:'Thomas', createdOn:'08-09-2016' }, 
   { name: 'Ho', createdBy:'Bob', createdOn:'07-09-2016', modifiedBy:'Alice', modifiedOn:'07-09-2016' },
   { name: 'Hoan', createdBy:'Thomas1', createdOn:'09-09-2016' }, 
   { name: 'Hieu', createdBy:'Bob', createdOn:'10-09-2016', modifiedBy:'Thomas1', modifiedOn:'07-09-2016' },
 ];
```

I dont want Bob beacuse Bob creation is modified by Alice in student name 'Ho'
and Hieu is modified by 'Thomas1'

my expected final output is in unique name of last updatedby

Bob is not eligible for this list ok...

```
Last updatedBy Last updated date 

------------    --------------

Thomas      09-09-2016

Alice       07-09-2016

Thomas1     09-09-2016
```

Comment: how do you defined unique here?

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes Ji i am struggling in this field I need a log report for last modifeid if modifiedBy is undefined means look createdBy any possiblity for this scenarion for getting this result

Comment: what do you want to do?and what have you done?

Comment: @jitendravarshney whether Its not posibble  ji. Thats why I am asking you understood my scenario?

Comment: Do you want to make that with angular filters?

Comment: @ManuelObregozo any other solution for getting my result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.filter('test', function() {
  return function(items) {
    var filtered = [];

    angular.forEach(items, function(el) {
      if(el.modifiedBy && el.modifiedOn) {
        el.createdBy = el.modifiedBy;
        el.createdOn = el.modifiedOn;
      }
    });
    for(var i = 1; i < items.length; ){
      if(items[i-1].createdBy == items[i].createdBy){
        items.splice(i, 1);
      } else {
        i++;
      }
    }
    return items;
  }
});
```

JsFiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/zv2un9hk/)

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing your problem statement into technical terms :

> If a record is modified, then the modifier becomes the creator. How do I find the unique creators ?

One of the solution would be :

```
var students = [  
   { name: 'Hai', createdBy:'Thomas', createdOn:'09-09-2016' },  
   { name: 'Hal', createdBy:'Thomas', createdOn:'08-09-2016' }, 
   { name: 'Ho', createdBy:'Bob', createdOn:'07-09-2016', modifiedBy:'Alice', modifiedOn:'07-09-2016' },
   { name: 'Hoan', createdBy:'Thomas1', createdOn:'09-09-2016' }, 
   { name: 'Hieu', createdBy:'Bob', createdOn:'10-09-2016', modifiedBy:'Thomas1', modifiedOn:'07-09-2016' },
 ]; 

var studentsTemp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(students));  //deep copy

var unique = {};
 for(var i = 0; i < studentsTemp.length; i ++){
    if(studentsTemp[i].modifiedBy != null){
        studentsTemp[i].createdBy = studentsTemp[i].modifiedBy;
    }
    unique[studentsTemp[i].createdBy] = studentsTemp[i].createdOn;
 }

 console.log(unique);
```

Convert this code into an `AngularJS` filter.